# How does stdio.h actually print to console (under the hood) in C on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, console, operating-system, printf

All the C programming language can do, without importing any libraries, is "basic" programming, i.e. creating for loops, defining a few data types, allocating memory etc.

On the other hand once we include < stdio.h > we are now able to print to the console. What on earth is happening here? How is C, a language with no ability to interface with the outside world "by itself", able to do so?

I know it has something to do with system calls and ultimately being converted to machine code, but my understanding is quite hazy and hand-wavey once I start to really think about it. Could anyone help me conceptually understand how < stdio.h > interfaces with Windows itself to actually display information on the screen?

Comment: It calls the operationg system (feeds the data into a pipe), and then the console reads and display that data. (obviously oversimplified). Here is a thing (it was made in a silly context): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxM8QmyZXtg&list=PLEMXAbCVnmY6zCgpCFlgggRkrp0tpWfrn It has in-depth explanations of the entire system (at some point).

Comment: The C routines like `putchar` call another library routine that does the write-to-device. That routine is part of a set of routines associated with the operating system. Somewhere in those routines, they execute some form of “system call” or “trap” instruction. When such an instruction is executed, the processor stops execution of your program and sends execution to a designated part of the operating system code. The operating system looks at what your program has requested and, if it is permitted, executes the request.

Comment: `stdio.h` is just a header file that includes a bunch of header files.  In that chain of includes are prototypes for functions like `printf` and `putchar` that are provided by libraries that are linked to your program when you build it.  Those library routines make OS specific calls to produce the I/O you ask for.

Answer (score 1):

> How is C, a language with no ability to interface with the outside
> world "by itself", able to do so?

Every language uses library functions or methods for this purpose.

C language can very easily communicate with the external world on a very low level without using any library functions.

Example (TFT driver registers exposed in the address space):

```
#define LCD  ((LCD_DataReg_Typedef *)(0x60000000))

typedef struct
{
    volatile uint16_t reg;            /* 0 */
    volatile uint16_t data;           /* 2 */
}LCD_DataReg_Typedef;

static INLINE void TFT_24_7789_StartWriteGRAM(void)
{
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Command(0x002c);
}

static INLINE void TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(uint16_t data)
{
    LCD -> data = data;
}

static INLINE uint16_t TFT_24_7789_Read_Data(void)
{
    return LCD -> data;
}

static INLINE void TFT_24_7789_Write_Command(uint16_t command)
{
    LCD -> reg = command;
}

void TFT_24_7789_SetOrientation(TFT_ORIENTATION orient)
{
    switch(orient)
    {
        case TFT_PORTRAIT:
            TFT_24_7789_Write_Command(0x0036);
            TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0b00000000);
            g7789.xSize = 240; g7789.ySize = 320;
            break;
        case TFT_PORTRAIT180:
            TFT_24_7789_Write_Command(0x0036);
            TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0b11000000);
            g7789.xSize = 240; g7789.ySize = 320;
            break;
        case TFT_LANDSCAPE:
            TFT_24_7789_Write_Command(0x0036);
            TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0b01100000);
            g7789.xSize = 320; g7789.ySize = 240;
            break;
        case TFT_LANDSCAPE180:
            TFT_24_7789_Write_Command(0x0036);
            TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0b10100000);
            g7789.xSize = 320; g7789.ySize = 240;
            break;
        default:
            return;
            break;
    }
    TFT_24_7789_SetWindow(0, g7789.xSize - 1, 0, g7789.ySize - 1);
}

void TFT_24_7789_Init(void)
{

    int n;
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Command(0x0011);
    //exit SLEEP mode
    TFT_delay(100);
    //MADCTL: memory data access control
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Command(0x003A);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0b01010101);
    //COLMOD: Interface Pixel format
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Command(0x00B2);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x000C);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x0C);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x00);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x33);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x33);
    //PORCTRK: Porch setting
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Command(0x00B7);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x0035);
    //GCTRL: Gate Control
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Command(0x00BB);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x002B);
    //VCOMS: VCOM setting
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Command(0x00C0);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x002C);
    //LCMCTRL: LCM Control
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Command(0x00C2);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x0001);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0xFF);
    //VDVVRHEN: VDV and VRH Command Enable
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Command(0x00C3);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x0011);
    //VRHS: VRH Set
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Command(0x00C4);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x0020);
    //VDVS: VDV Set
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Command(0x00C6);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x000F);
    //FRCTRL2: Frame Rate control in normal mode
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Command(0x00D0);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x00A4);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0xA1);
    //PWCTRL1: Power Control 1
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Command(0x00E0);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x00D0);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x0000);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x0005);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x000E);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x0015);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x000D);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x0037);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x0043);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x0047);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x0009);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x0015);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x0012);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x0016);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x0019);
    //PVGAMCTRL: Positive Voltage Gamma control
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Command(0x00E1);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x00D0);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x0000);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x0005);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x000D);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x000C);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x0006);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x002D);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x0044);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x0040);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x000E);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x001C);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x0018);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x0016);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(0x0019);
    //NVGAMCTRL: Negative Voltage Gamma control
    TFT_24_7789_SetOrientation(TFT_LANDSCAPE);
    TFT_delay(10);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Command(0x0029);
}

void TFT_24_7789_SetWindow(uint16_t xStart, uint16_t xEnd, uint16_t yStart, uint16_t yEnd)
{

//  TFT_24_7789_Write_Command(0x0028);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Command(0x002A);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(xStart >> 8);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(xStart & 0xff);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(xEnd >> 8);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(xEnd & 0xff);

    TFT_24_7789_Write_Command(0x002B);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(yStart >> 8);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(yStart & 0xff);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(yEnd >> 8);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(yEnd & 0xff);
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Command(0x0029);
}


void GUI_PutPixelFAST(uint32_t xpos, uint32_t ypos, uint32_t colour)
{
    TFT_24_7789_SetWindow(xpos, xpos, ypos, ypos);
    TFT_24_7789_StartWriteGRAM();
    TFT_24_7789_Write_Data(colour);
}
/* and much more */
```

Now we can draw pixel. Using pixels we can write functions which will print character. Then we can print strings. Wihout using even a single standard library functions.